# How to add a image to cloud9?

Tags: html, css, cloud9-ide

I have googled and searched for this but I need help. I feel really stupid because I have been using ide's for awhile. Just not cloud based. So how do I add a local image to my cloud9 html page?

Comment: try to add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could upload your image online then use `href` to use the online link.

Otherwise, if you'd still like your image to be local, you can upload files to your workspace like [this](http://www.cloud9realtime.com/knowledgebase/how-do-i-upload-files-to-cloud9-from-my-local-computer).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew how to link to a online image. Just didnt want to rely on a web hosted image that can be removed at anytime. but thank you

Answer (score 3):

you can also use a simple save and drag method.

- save the image in your images folder on your desktop (or where ever)
- open cloud9 project so that you can see your file hierarchy
- click on image saved to your computer
- drag and drop into images folder
  this is as of 03/2016

Comment: Confirmed that this works now as well, hasn't changed even though AWS acquired cloud9

Answer (score 0):

This works on rails projects on c9, not sure about different environments but worth a try.

curl -O imagelink

mv imagelink app/assets/images/