# Uploaded picture not showing up on Cloud 9 Test Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I am having trouble with getting uploaded images to show on a Cloud 9 rails project. When I run rails and use the included test browser I simply get a blue question mark. Calling images via their url works.

I have checked the following for help and they were unable to assist me:

1. [How to add a image to cloud9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069283/how-to-add-a-image-to-cloud9)

Here is the code so far: 
https://jsbin.com/nuduco/edit?html,output

Here is the directory structure: 
[Folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SpsU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 IDE loads page previews over https by default. Be sure the image is being loaded over https or else you'll get a cross-origin issue. Alternatively, you can pop the preview out into a new tab and then change the preview to http.